# jQuery UI adding placeholder to combobox

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, combobox

I'm having some trouble with jQuery UI's combobox. I'm trying to add the source select's placeholder to the ui's input, so I can easily set everything up on my element and have the widget just pick up on what's needed. However it doesn't seem to want a placeholder separated by any spaces/symbols and only applies the first word.

I've tried:

```
input = $("<input data-validation='required' placeholder=" + select.attr('placeholder') + ">")
```

And replacing spaces with hifen and underscores (example placeholder in this case ="Start-typing" or "Start_typing"):

```
input = $("<input data-validation='required' placeholder=" + select.attr('placeholder') + ">").replace(/-/g, ' ')
```

I've also tried applying the text to the title attribute and getting it the same way, but it has the same result.

I finally tried doing the following:

```
placeholder = select.attr('placeholder').replace(/-/g, ' ');
console.log(placeholder);
input = $("<input data-validation='required' placeholder="+placeholder+">")...
```

I can see the placeholder's value is correct before being applied to the input, so I'm at a loss as to where to go from here. Any ideas?

The [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/uxQ29/) contains the whole widget configuration along with some validation I was testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to add quotes in your HTML string:

```
input = $('<input data-validation="required" placeholder="' + select.attr('placeholder') + '">');
```

Otherwise, it'll treat words 2 through n as additional attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can change .js file of the combobox by adding processing properties that you set to select control.
For example you have regular select:

```
<select id="YourId" placeholder="Some Text">...</select>
```

Than:

```
  $(function () {
        $("#YourId").combobox();
        $("#toggle").click(function () {
            $("#YourId").toggle();
        });
    });
```

And edit combobox script by adding line

```
this.input.attr("placeholder", this.element.attr('placeholder'));
```

Like this:

```
(function ($) {         
$.widget("custom.combobox", {
            _create: function () {
                this.wrapper = $("<span>")
                  .addClass("custom-combobox")
                  .insertAfter(this.element);

                this.element.hide();
                this._createAutocomplete();
                this._createShowAllButton();

                // Add processing placeholder option
                this.input.attr("placeholder", this.element.attr('placeholder'));            
            },
    ..... 
    });})(jQuery);
```

In such way you also can add any other option as "readonly" etc.